# mybatis lombok Error instantiating class

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, lombok

I am trying to use mybatis for connecting local mysql databse, and lombok for POJO object, but I got "Error instantiating class" error. I googled some results, seems like I need to create constructor for the POJO, but I am think do I have to do that if I am using lombok?

Admin.java

package com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

```
@Builder
@Data
public class Admin {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String userName;
}
```

Stack Trace

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin.<init>()

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin.<init>()
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin.<init>()
    org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:160)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:95)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.mybatis.dao.impl.AdminDaoImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminDaoImpl.java:24)
    com.cooldrinker.dataservice.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminServiceImpl.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.controller.AdminLoginController.login(AdminLoginController.java:39)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin.<init>()
    org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:83)
    org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:376)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:355)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.getRowValue(FastResultSetHandler.java:255)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:214)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:186)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:152)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:57)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:141)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:101)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:59)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:160)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:95)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.mybatis.dao.impl.AdminDaoImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminDaoImpl.java:24)
    com.cooldrinker.dataservice.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminServiceImpl.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.controller.AdminLoginController.login(AdminLoginController.java:39)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.cooldrinker.mybatis.model.Admin.<init>()
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2902)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066)
    org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:57)
    org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:376)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:355)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.getRowValue(FastResultSetHandler.java:255)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:214)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:186)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:152)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:57)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:141)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
    org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:101)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95)
    org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:59)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:160)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:95)
    org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.mybatis.dao.impl.AdminDaoImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminDaoImpl.java:24)
    com.cooldrinker.dataservice.service.impl.AdminServiceImpl.getAdminByUsername(AdminServiceImpl.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.getAdminByUsername(Unknown Source)
    com.cooldrinker.controller.AdminLoginController.login(AdminLoginController.java:39)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without reading the documentation, I think you might need a no-args constructor. You only have the all-args constructor. You can tell Lombok to generate both by adding `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` to the type.

Answer (score 1):

From the lombok documentation (https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html):

"Finally, applying @Builder to a class is as if you added @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE) to the class and applied the @Builder annotation to this all-args-constructor. This only works if you haven't written any explicit constructors yourself. If you do have an explicit constructor, put the @Builder annotation on the constructor instead of on the class."

So, in order to MyBatis use the non argument constructor you must add it to the class. On the other hand, your resultMap can use the `<constructor>` tag in order to use the generated constructor.